# APC SmartUPS - "StayOff by UI for: 60s", what does this mean?

Tags: ups

I have a SmartUPS 1500 LCD (circa 2009 with original batteries) connected to my Linux server running APCUPSD. Last week, I had a power cut and the server shut down automatically when the battery ran low. The power came back a couple of hours later, and I discovered that the UPS didn't switch itself off - though still powering my router and AirPort, the battery was lasting fine without the load of the server on it. After booting the server back up, I noticed that the LCD panel keeps displaying 'UPS StayOff by UI for: 60s'. I cannot work out what this means. Pushing any button dismisses the message, but not permanently - after a few seconds idle, it returns. Pushing the arrow keys does not change the number like the colon implies. Also, when dismissing the message, the previous UI does not do its normal loop (I have Advanced Menus enabled, so the idle display shows parameters like input/output voltage, load, estimated battery runtime etc. in a loop), but sits on whatever screen I select until the message comes back. I can't work out how to dismiss it permanently. Googling doesn't reveal much. Any ideas?

Comment: You could contact APC tech support.

Comment: @fixer1234 I guess. I bought the UPS second-hand so I don't have proof of purchase though :)

Comment: That doesn't matter.  It's a technical question about their product.

Answer (score 0):

Predictably, APC support did not respond to my email.
I was able to fix the issue by rebooting the UPS, but obviously this is not ideal. If anyone knows a better way, I'd love to hear it!